# Prove $\lim_{\delta\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(\delta x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)dx$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ continuous and it's support is compact, why can we use convergence dominated to prove $$\lim_{\delta\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(\delta x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)dx.$$

**My idea is:**

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\delta x)\to f(x)$ when $\delta\to 1$. Now let denote $S$ it's support. Suppose that $\delta\leq 2$. Then $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(\delta x)|dx=\int_{\delta S}|f(\delta x)|dx\leq\int_{2S}|f(\delta x)|dx.$$

But is $x\mapsto f(\delta x)$ is well defined on $2S$ ? May be I have a problem with the definition. For example, is $f:]0,\infty ]\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}-1&x\leq 1\\ 0& otherwise\end{cases}$$
is a continuous function with compact support ? I would says yes since it's support is $[0,1]$, but in other time, it's not define on $0$, so may be it doesn't work. So is the support has to be included in the domain of the function ?

Comment: You could also change variable $\delta x = y$.

Comment: A function with compact support $S$ is defined on whole $R^d$ (and on $2S$ in particular).

Comment: @NikitaEvseev: this is not true. It can be continuously extend on all $\mathbb R^d$, but it's not defined on all $\mathbb R^d$ a priori. If you say that $g$ has compact support on $(a,b)$, it mean that it's support is compact and included in $(a,b)$. It's not necessary to extend it on all $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: @Rick Agree it can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just write down the change of variable
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(\delta x)dx = \frac{1}{\delta^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)dy,
$$
and it is tends to $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)dx$ as $\delta\to1$.

Comment: It's not the answer I was waiting for, but $+1$ for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The support of a function is a subset of it's domain, therefore the support of your function is $]0,1]$ and not $[0,1]$, and thus it's not a function with compact support. If $g$ is continuous with compact support $S$ then you can set $$h(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&x\in S\\ 0& x\notin S\end{cases}$$
wich is a continuous function on all $\mathbb R$. So, for your problem,$$|f(\delta x)|\leq M$$
where $M$ is the maximum of $f$ on $2S$ and since $M$ is integrable on $2S$ (since it's compact), you can apply dominated convergence theorem and conclude that $$\lim_{\delta\to 1}\int_{2S}f(\delta x)dx=\int_{2S}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)dx.$$